# Saving WinForms MDI forms state under .net

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have an MDI layout WinForms application. I'd like to save its opened forms state (size, text box values, selected list indexes...) when closing app to retrieve them at a new startup.

There are plenty of ways to do it, but I did not find a solution to save this data, if there are more open instances of a given form in an MDI app. E.g. if I have 2 opened instances of Form1 that has a textbox. TextBox's text on instance 1 is 'a' and on instance 2 is 'b'. If I save it e.g. to app.config by using .net's features, instance2's settings will overwrite instance1's saved data, because they're the same type.So when loading at start it would be 'b' for both instances.

How can I save their state separately? How to identify them when saving them?

Comment: Clearly you'll need to persist a list of forms, not just a single one.  Nothing built-in but easy enough to get going with xml serialization.

Comment: I use a dockable window component that enables to persist UI layout, so I don't need that. It persists the layout, I have to persist 'only' the data on UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement it as described. You can save only one/last state because there is no a way to determinate which version should be restored.

But you can use a named state storage to achive the goal.

You should create you own storage that should provide two methods

```
interface IStateStorage
{
  UIState LoadState(string name);
  void SaveState(string name, State state);
}
```

You can store or recover UI state in anytime when you need it by loading state with other name.

In case of your question you can save UI state twice
At first time it will save default state ss.SaveState("default", state) that will overwrite default state.
At second time it will save named state ss.SaveState("a", state) that will overwrite named state.

On form open you will able to choose which state should be restored a default one or another named one.